# Audio continues playing after switching users

Tags: sound, 18.04, pulseaudio, alsa

I am currently using Ubuntu 18.04, but had same problem with 16.04.

Current situation:
If a program is running in the background by another user and it makes a sound, the sound is played regardless of what user is actively using the computer.

Desired behavior:
Only the currently active user's programs play sound.

pulseaudio --dump-conf indicates system-instance=no and local-server-type=user. I am unsure what logs/configs would be useful for figuring this out. I am not even sure whether this is a pulseaudio or an alsa problem, since apparently Ubuntu uses both.

Answer (score 0):

That is probably working like currently designed. When switching users, all application of that user keep running by design. You may need to rely somewhat on the citizenship and discipline of the other users and ask them to close audio players when they leave the computer, or ask help of a user with root privileges (that might be you) to terminate these processes of the other user.